# Why is the server rejecting my PDO query?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, pdo

I've been trying to write a simple search and display site with a drop down menu, I've tried using mysqli and PDO and I'm not getting the results. I've just checked the server log in cpanel and found that the access has been denied to the results page. The access must be all right for the drop down page as it is populating the drop down list. I can't see why it is being stopped. The server is running PHP 5.3.27 and MYSQL 5.5.36.

This is the drop down.

```
 <form action="search3.php" method="post" >

<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user','password','engraved_stamps');
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM engravers ORDER BY Country";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    ?>
    <select >
    <?php

       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<option value=\"{$row['Country']}\">";
         echo $row['Country'];
         echo "</option>";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
      </select>

              <input type="submit" name="dropdown" />   
              </form>
```

This is the results page (action for restul) (called Search3.php)

```
    <?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password,);
    if(!$connection){
    echo"Could not connect to server";
    };
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'engraved_stamps');
    if(!mysqli_select_db($connection,'engraved_stamps')){
    echo"could not connect to database";
    };

    if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])){
    $Country = $_POST['dropdown'];
    }else{
    $Country = "none";
    }
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = :Country";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Country', $Country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = $stmt->rowCount();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    echo $row->Country;
    }

    $mysqli->close();

        ?>
```

Comment: The connection is being opened differently - might be worth checking into.

Comment: You are mixing mysqli and PDO...

Comment: I'm not getting any message when I post but when I looked at the cpanel log there were about 300 rejections. Now I've looked again I can see that none of them seem to be this file. They are all from other files that I have on the server for a program called Zencart. I suspect these may be interfering in some way. Does that sound likely?

Comment: I tried adding both the same way but it was no different.

Comment: I'm not intentionally mixing Alvaro. Would you mind pointing out where that is happening. That could be the problem.

Comment: You may want to remove that password from your code :) **Edit:** did it for you.

Comment: Thanks. That's the biggest mistake. It was due for a change anyway so now it had better happen.

Comment: Did you check apache error logs?

Comment: The server runs on Apache (I think) and the only error log I can find is the one on cpanel.

Comment: I think mixing mysqli and PDO is probably the main problem. I'll attack that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two entirely different database extensions:

1. [MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/mysqli) (aka *mysqli*):

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli(...)
                 ^^^^^^
   ```
2. [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/pdo) (aka *PDO*):

   ```
   $stmt->bindParam(':Country', $Country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                          ^^^
   ```

Despite your question title and tags, your code seems to use mysqli entirely. You'll just need to get rid of the PDO bits.

You're also using some undefined variables:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        ^^^^
```

You're apparently not getting the corresponding error messages, which suggests you haven't configured your PHP development box to do so. As soon as you do it, you'll be possibly warned of some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think PDO and mysqli are different PHP extensions. You should choose only one thing to deal with your work.

e.g., you can use mysqli only, or PDO.

For more information about PDO, see: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try {
    //here add user and password and database please be sure u have used correct one
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=engraved_stamps",'root','');
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

<?php

$STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM engravers WHERE Country = :Country");
 if(isset($_POST['dropdown'])){
    $Country = $_POST['dropdown'];
    }else{
    $Country = "name";//here you can assing % too for value of any if u need tell me to recode, NOTE here now the value u have assign is (name) is the record value on ur engravers table for column of Country.
    }


$STM->bindParam(':Country', $Country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STM->execute();                    
$row= $STM->fetchAll();
 if(count($row)){
    foreach($row as $data){
        echo $data['Country'] . "<br />";// here country is the column of ur table u can echo other columns too
    }
 }else {
    echo 'no row found';
 }

?>
```

Comment: This is trying to work but keeps giving a result of "no row found. Is there something else I need to add? Also, I'm not sure what I should be putting where it says "name". At least I'm getting the error messages now.

Comment: Sorry for late here at "name"  is example may in ur database u have other so it show none row found now write me ur table structure and one row data

Comment: Thanks. This may be where the problem is. I reloaded the database recently and I notice that everything is listed as not null. would that mean that a blank space would stop it? Here is the structure:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry abas_rafiq. the comments only allow a certain number of characters.
Here is the structure:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `engravers` (
  `Key` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StampImages` text NOT NULL,
  `Images` text NOT NULL,
  `Country` text NOT NULL,
  `Year` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  `SGNumber` text NOT NULL,
  `ScottNumber` text NOT NULL,
  `Engraver1Surname` text NOT NULL,
  `Engraver1OtherNames` text NOT NULL,
  `Engraver2Surname` text NOT NULL,
  `Engraver2OtherNames` text NOT NULL,
  `Engraver3Surname` text NOT NULL,
  `Engraver3OtherNames` text NOT NULL,
  `Designer1Surname` text NOT NULL,
  `Designer1OtherNames` text NOT NULL,
  `Designer2Surname` text NOT NULL,
  `Designer2OtherNames` text NOT NULL,
  `Printer` text NOT NULL,
  `Notes` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Key` (`Key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=91 ;
They were not all "Not Null" when I set it up but I see they are now.

Comment: Write your one row data in this table

Comment: Key:10 StampImages: AU180.jpg Images: AU180_small.jpg Country: Australia Year 1938 Description: 1d Emerald Queen Elizabeth SGNumber: AU180 ScottNumber: AU180 Engraver1Surname: Manley Engraver1OtherNames: Frank Davies Engraver2Surname: Duffel Engraver2OtherNames: Thomas C. Engraver3Surname: blank Engraver3OtherNames: blank Designer1Surname: Manley Designer1OtherNames: Frank Davies Designer2Surname: blank Designer2OtherNames: blank Printer: John Ash Notes: Also printed by W.C.G. McCracken  I hope that all makes sense.

Comment: I have found the problem. The results written by abas_rafiq are working perfectly. Thankyou. The problem was in my drop down. I removed the back slash from the end of the input row (not sure even why it was there) and moved the name="dropdown up into the brackets with "select". That was all it took so now we have a simple drop down search that works. Thanks to everyone who helped.